# Fixed-Width vs Adaptive Binning

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, data, data-cleaning

I have some continuous variable in my data that I wish to apply binning for. The values range from 0 to 800 but I got motivated by the fact that the data distribution was left skewed as you could see in the following figure:
[image]

However, I have read this amazing blog about binning data [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-feature-engineering-part-1-continuous-numeric-data-da4e47099a7b) whereby the author claims that `adaptive binning` is better than `fixed-width binning`. I understand the idea behind this because the some of the bins that we define in the fixed-width approach may have too little data distribution in comparison to other bins, which won't be a fair game to play whereby the adaptive approach, motivated by the idea of `quantiles` is better. Are there any more arguments, or more in depth analysis, of this hypothesis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at that link.  It's pretty informative.  As you already know, The `cut` function is used to specifically define the bin edges.  There is no guarantee about the distribution of items in each bin.  In fact, you can define bins in such a way that no items are included in a bin or nearly all items are in a single bin.  The `qcut` function is slightly different.  The `qcut` function tries to divide up the underlying data into equal sized bins.  The function defines the bins using percentiles based on the distribution of the data, not the actual numeric edges of the bins.  In conclusion, if you want equal distribution of the items in your bins, use `qcut` . If you want to define your own numeric bin ranges, then use `cut`.

See the link below for more details.

https://pbpython.com/pandas-qcut-cut.html